# Can't figure out why I'm being routed to login view, instead of dashboard, when I create a user?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, csrf, basic-authentication

I have looked high and low and can't figure out why I am being re-routed to login rather than dashboard upon creating a user. 
The idea is to automatically be logged into and be re-routed to the Dashboard when a new user is created.

I'm new to Node please help!

```js
// Import Modules/Libraries =====================

// takes body of req and parse to whatever using post()/put()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// add encryption library
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
// add form input security csrf
var csrf = require('csurf');
// add express framework for node
var express = require('express');
// add ORM for mongodb
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// add sessions library - BEST security options in this library
var sessions = require('client-sessions');

// Create / Use Module =====================

  // sew express into the 'app'
var app = express();
  // log Server message to show server is running
  console.log("Yo Adrian!... Our Server is now running!");

// Connect to Database =====================

  // connect to mongo
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/newauth');

// Creating Users =====================
 
  // create Schema variables for generating user id''s in the database
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
  
  // use mongoose to generate the user id
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

  // Create Schema -- 
    // define an the object called 'User'
    // using mongoose model which essentially represents a user in a database
    // id will be created by mongodb

var User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: {type: String, unique: true},
  password: String
}));


// Set the Template Engine =====================

  // Use Jade view engine
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Misc. Adjustments =====================
  
  // Cleanup HTML Minification
app.locals.pretty = true;

// Middelware =====================

    // - Before running routes, parse the request(s)
    // - When a request comes in body-parser turn it into an object for us
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(sessions({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'skjdhfkjhvntruieowoeijervhfncmsyeiwuirdjhjfhdjnmcneiuoasad', // used to encrypt & decrypt info from a session
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000, // amount of miliseconds before a cookie expires, (absolute limit - 30 min)
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000 // by setting this it lengthens the session so user wont get kicked out
}));

app.use(csrf());

// GLOBAL Middleware =====================

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.session && req.session.user){
    User.findOne({email: req.session.user.email }, function(err, user){
      if(user){
        req.user = user;
        delete req.user.password;
        req.session.user  = req.user;
        res.locals.user = req.user;
      }
        next();
    });
  }else{
    next();
  }
});


// GLOBAL Functions =====================

function requireLogin(req, res, next){
  if(!req.user){
    res.redirect('/login'); 
  }else{
    next();
  }
};

// Create Routes =====================

  // Index Page
app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.render('index.jade');
});
  // Register Page
    // Get the info our user sends to us 
      // Inject CSRF encryption token into page/form    
app.get('/register', function(req, res){
  res.render('register.jade', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
});
    // Send it back to the browser with the data they sent us as json
app.post('/register', function(req, res){
  
  // res.json(req.body); ** this was to test json in step one

  // generate a bcrpyt hashed password
  var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));

    // Here we create a new instance of the User model/schema above.
  var user = new User({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hash // store hashe password in db
  });

  user.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      var err = "Something Bad Happend! Try again!";

        if(err.code === 11000){
            error = "That email is already taken, try another!";
        }

      res.render('register.jade', { error: error });
    }else{
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
  });
});

  // Login Page
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login.jade', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  User.findOne({email: req.body.email }, function(err, user){
    console.log("Querying...");
    // If it is not the user?
    if(!user){
      // then ender error!
      res.render('login.jade', {error:'Invalid email or password.'});
             console.log('Login attempt failed');
    }else{
         // otherwise check if passwords match using bcrypt function
      if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)){
          
            console.log("Attempting to login... ");

          // if they match assign a session to a user
        req.session.user = user;
          
           console.log('req.session.user = ' + req.session.user);

        // redirect to the dashboard
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
          console.log('Login attempt Successful');
      }else{
        // Otherwise if they dont match render error!
        res.render('login.jade', {error:'Invalid email or password.'});
          console.log('Login attempt failed altogether');
      }
    }
  });
});
  // Dashboard Page
app.get('/dashboard', requireLogin, function(req, res){
    res.render('dashboard.jade');
});
  // Redirected Routes
    // Logout Page
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.session.reset(); // Delete session
  res.redirect('/');
});

// Listen on Port 3000 =====================
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out! I needed to create a function that added a new user and call that function in registration. See below revised code:

```js
// Import Modules/Libraries =====================

// takes body of req and parse to whatever using post()/put()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// add encryption library
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
// add form input security csrf
var csrf = require('csurf');
// add express framework for node
var express = require('express');
// add ORM for mongodb
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// add sessions library - BEST security options in this library
var sessions = require('client-sessions');

// Create / Use Module =====================

  // sew express into the 'app'
var app = express();
  // log Server message to show server is running
  console.log("Yo Adrian!... Our Server is now running!");

// Connect to Database =====================

  // connect to mongo
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/newauth');

// Creating Users =====================
 
  // create Schema variables for generating user id''s in the database
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
  
  // use mongoose to generate the user id
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

  // Create Schema -- 
    // define an the object called 'User'
    // using mongoose model which essentially represents a user in a database
    // id will be created by mongodb

var User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: {type: String, unique: true},
  password: String
}));


// Set the Template Engine =====================

  // Use Jade view engine
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Misc. Adjustments =====================
  
  // Cleanup HTML Minification
app.locals.pretty = true;

// Middelware =====================

    // - Before running routes, parse the request(s)
    // - When a request comes in body-parser turn it into an object for us
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(sessions({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'skjdhfkjhvntruieowoeijervhfncmsyeiwuirdjhjfhdjnmcneiuoasad', // used to encrypt & decrypt info from a session
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000, // amount of miliseconds before a cookie expires, (absolute limit - 30 min)
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000 // by setting this it lengthens the session so user wont get kicked out
}));

app.use(csrf());

// GLOBAL Middleware =====================

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.session && req.session.user){
    User.findOne({email: req.session.user.email }, 'firstName lastName email data', function(err, user){
      if(user){
        req.user = user;
        delete req.user.password;
        req.session.user  = req.user;
        res.locals.user = req.user;
      }
        next();
    });
  }else{
    next();
  }
});

createUserSession = function(req, res, user) {
  var cleanUser = {
    firstName:  user.firstName,
    lastName:   user.lastName,
    email:      user.email,
    data:       user.data || {},
  };

  req.session.user = cleanUser;
  req.user = cleanUser;
  res.locals.user = cleanUser;
};



// GLOBAL Functions =====================

function requireLogin(req, res, next){
  if(!req.user){
    res.redirect('/login'); 
  }else{
    next();
  }
};

// Create Routes =====================

  // Index Page
app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.render('index.jade');
});
  // Register Page
    // Get the info our user sends to us 
      // Inject CSRF encryption token into page/form    
app.get('/register', function(req, res){
  res.render('register.jade', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
});

    // Send it back to the browser with the data they sent us as json
app.post('/register', function(req, res){
  
  // res.json(req.body); ** this was to test json in step one

  // generate 10 character salt
  var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  // generate a bcrpyt hashed password
  var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt); 

    // Here we create a new instance of the User model/schema above.
  var user = new User({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hash // store hashe password in db
  });

  user.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      var err = "Something Bad Happend! Try again!";

        if(err.code === 11000){
            error = "That email is already taken, try another!";
        }

      res.render('register.jade', { error: error });
    }else{
      console.log('Saved... Redirecting to Dashboard!!');
      createUserSession(req, res, user);
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
  });
});

  // Login Page
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login.jade', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  User.findOne({email: req.body.email }, function(err, user){
    console.log("Querying...");
    // If it is not the user?
    if(!user){
      // then ender error!
      res.render('login.jade', {error:'Invalid email or password.'});
             console.log('Login attempt failed');
    }else{
         // otherwise check if passwords match using bcrypt function
      if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)){
          
            console.log("Attempting to login... ");

          // if they match assign a session to a user
        req.session.user = user;
          
           console.log('req.session.user = ' + req.session.user);

        // redirect to the dashboard
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
          console.log('Login attempt Successful');
      }else{
        // Otherwise if they dont match render error!
        res.render('login.jade', {error:'Invalid email or password.'});
          console.log('Login attempt failed altogether');
      }
    }
  });
});
  // Dashboard Page
app.get('/dashboard', requireLogin, function(req, res){
    res.render('dashboard.jade');
});
  // Redirected Routes
    // Logout Page
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.session.reset(); // Delete session
  res.redirect('/');
});

// Listen on Port 3000 =====================
app.listen(3000);
```